# audio library on simulator

Tags: iphone

One of my projects needs to load audio from audio library. It works on my iPod touch. But I prefer to debug on simulator. The audio library on simulator is empty, so I need to add some audios to the audio library on simulator.

What is the path of audio library on simulator?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Music" or "iPod" "application" is simply not present on the simulator. So you really can't debug the audio library part on the simulator, unfortunately.